# use pandas map on a complex column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, mapping

Here is what my csv looks like

| time | cause |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | a / b / c |
| 42 | c / d / a / b |
| 12 | a / d / e |
| 98 | c / b / e / d |

and this is the output I am trying to achieve

| time | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 42 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 98 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

My real data is much larger, but this example should get me what I am looking for. I can not figure out how to use the map function to check for multiple possible values in every cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and `join` back to the original dataframe:

```py
df[['time']].join(df['cause'].str.get_dummies(sep=' / '))
```

or using `pop` for modification of the original dataframe:

```py
df = df.join(df.pop('cause').str.get_dummies(sep=' / '))
```

output:

```
   time  a  b  c  d  e
0    23  1  1  1  0  0
1    42  1  1  1  1  0
2    12  1  0  0  1  1
3    98  0  1  1  1  1
```